# Too many redirects when making a call to ASP.NET Web API 2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-session

On making a POST call to a ASP.NET Web API 2 . I get the PostAUthorize_Request fired repeatedly . This results in an error . What could the problem here be ?

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS [http://localhost/FT/API/V2/AuthenticateUser/validate]
```

[image]

Comment: Please do not post images of your code - post your code. If the image gets lost, your question becomes a lot less solveable.

Comment: Since this is a post authorize event, I imagine, something is fishy with the auth workflow and your user keeps being re-authenticated and that is why this method keeps being raised. I suggest you steph through your code and find out why that redirect is happening.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when the application is setup in a way where an original incoming request ends up in a redirect loop. One example that I have myself managed to create (and subsequently had to fix) is this:

- The login page for the application is buggy and causes an `Exception` to be thrown
- All unhandled exceptions are caught at the application level and shown through a redirect to an error page
- But the error page itself requires you to be logged in first

When an unauthenticated request first comes in, it gets redirected to the login page, which throws an exception, causing a redirect to the error page, which requires an authenticated user so it redirects to the login page. And so on forever until the browser just stops the madness.

There are other similar redirect loops that can occur, so you need to investigate what the loop is (if indeed it is a loop). Personally I would use a third party tool like `Fiddler` to do this. Many other options are, I'm sure, also available.